# Google Calendar in unity

Tags: 14.04, unity, calendar, google-calendar

Is there a way to sync google calendar with **unity without adding new software** ??

If there isn't a way can you recommend the **light weight software** for this task?? that will have the ability to notify my about the alarms etc...

Thank you for your time

Comment: Evolution comes with Ubuntu that can interface with GMail and import all your calendar entries.

Comment: Hm does it integrates it in default calender ?? because  I can't manage anything from my ubuntu calendar menu

Comment: I just set mine up with Evolution, and my calendar that I use in Ubuntu has updated automatically with my GMail account.  I did go into preferences and made my GMail the only calendar I am using, then it updates across all my devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evolution isn't particularly light-weight, HOWEVER imho it's the best email program out there and you should be using it anyway.

Evolution synchronizes your Google Calendar and you can see your next 5 appointments (or at least I currently see 5 appointments there, I don't know whether it only shows a maximum of 5 appointments but also with a time limit past which appointments are ignored) when you click on the date in the upper right corner of you screen.

Notice that Evolution has an option to add Google Calendars which worked when I set up Evolution for Ubuntu 14.04. However, it doesn't work with the version currently in the Ubuntu 14.04 repositories because it can't load the page it tries to load. So probably Google has changed something.

But you still can add your calendars. Add a calendar of the type `CalDAV` with these parameters:

```
URL: https://www.google.com/calendar/dav/[your email address]/events
User: [your email address]
Email: [empty]
```

The rest is self-explanatory.

Comment: I don't understand how did the gnome and unity dev teams came to a conclusion not to have any kind of online or offline calendar management. first time I needed to add an even on my ubuntu calendar I opened it and started pressing the date I was interested in, boy I was surprised that I could not add anything to the calendar.

about Evolution I need to install it right because even though I have evolution apps running I don't think they are the thing I am interested in?

Comment: I don't have a system without Evolution, so I can't check for it. But Evolution has different packages and it wouldn't surprise me to learn that there is at least one package pre-installed on Ubuntu to provide the calendar in Unity because back when Evolution (the entire application) was pre-installed and Gnome 2 was used, Evolution was used as the standard calendar application with that very same integrated mini calendar in the upper-right corner. But the graphical interface together with the email functionality was later removed from the pre-installed packages.

Comment: Well thank you for the reply sadly i need to install it, I am going to try my luck with unity design team maybe if I nag enough they will implement it :)

Comment: doesn't work, always prompt password incorrect, it's the same error as ubuntu account management for Google

Comment: @tribbloid make sure your email address in the URL and the User box  includes the full user@gmail.com.  Same thing happened to me until I fixed those.

Comment: @tribbloid Check gmail through your browser, at least for me google blocked Evolution automatically because it didn't fit "modern security standards".

Comment: @tribbloid Just found a fix for this (not recommended though): https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

Unity in Ubuntu 14.04 (the version tagged in the question) comes with an Online Accounts application that allows you to sign into your Google account.  One of the results of logging into your Google account is that by default you will receive popup notifications at the times designated in your Google calendar events.  A list of the next 5 events are also available by clicking on the Date-Time in the top bar.  This does not require installing any additional software/packages.

Here is a complete list of the Online Accounts that are currently supported:

1. Facebook
2. Flickr
3. Google
4. Twitter
5. AIM
6. Salut
7. Jabber
8. Yahoo!